# Get number of rows for all combinations of attribute levels in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe bunch of categorical variables, each row corresponds to a product.I wanted to find the number of rows for every combination of attribute levels and decided to run the following:

```
att1=list(frame_base.columns.values)
f1=att.groupby(att1,as_index=False).size().rename('counts').to_frame()
```

***att1*** is the list of all attributes, ***f1*** does not seem to provide the correct value as ***f1.counts.sum()***  is not equal to ***len(f1)*** before the group by.Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Do you think instead `frame_base` - `att` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible problem is `NaN` row, but maybe there is typo - need `att` instead `frame_base`:

```
att = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3,np.nan],
                   'B':[1,1,6,np.nan],
                   'C':[2,2,9,np.nan],
                   'D':[1,1,5,np.nan],
                   'E':[1,1,6,np.nan],
                   'F':[1,1,3,np.nan]})

print (att)
     A    B    C    D    E    F
0  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  3.0  6.0  9.0  5.0  6.0  3.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

att1=list(att.columns.values)
f1=att.groupby(att1).size().reset_index(name='counts')
print (f1)
     A    B    C    D    E    F  counts
0  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  1.0  1.0       2
1  3.0  6.0  9.0  5.0  6.0  3.0       1
```